# git bash shell .bashrc not working every time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a .git directory in my Dropbox, to store data for my website. In the directory, I have a `.bashrc` file, like this:

[directory and .bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lef8u.png)

When I type this into the bash terminal, it echo's

```
$ source .bashrc
my login
```

but when I restart terminal, it echo's nothing. I have to source it again.

I've read a few posts about this issue, about having to source it again and again but they said that if you do it to .bashrc it will work everytime. Mine doesn't. Where am I messing up?

Comment: `.bashrc` needs to be in the home directory of your shell. Am I reading your question right that you have it, not in your home directory, but in your dropbox folder?

Comment: Does home directory mean where the program is installed? I am running windows by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `bash` goes looking for its startup files, it generally looks for `.bashrc` in your *home* directory (where it currently isn't).

If you want to source a separate `.bashrc` file, probably the easiest solution is to put something like this into your *actual* one (the one that `bash` will run), `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
otherOne="/somewhere/else/.bashrc"
if [[ -x "${otherOne}" ]] ; then
    . "${otherOne}"
fi
```

Comment: A file does not need to be executable to be sourced, just readable.

Comment: @chepner, that's really just a way to decide whether it runs or not. Mark it non-x and it won't be actioned. Actually, I just totally made that up but it *could* have been the reason why I did it :-)

Comment: Fair enough, then. :)

Comment: omg thanks so much, i am new to git and not really good with linux, but this claered it up , thanks alot